# Eclipse Auto-Complete (Template Functions)

Tags: eclipse

I like to use auto-complete in Eclipse and it works fine most of the time.

However, in template functions:

```
template <class T> int existeEmPilha (const stack<**T**> &stack1, const T &v1){

stack1.(...) //it does not complete
}
```

But it works fine in the case:

```
template <class T> int existeEmPilha (const stack<**int**> &stack1, const T &v1){

stack1.(...) //auto-complete appears with functions like size(), pop(), etc...
}
```

I need to do template functions and I would like to use auto-complete when doing so. Is it possible?

I'm using Eclipse Juno SR1.

Answer (score 1):

In order to make a new function template go on
Eclipse > Preferences... > Java > Editor > Templates

You will see there the set of templates that has been already defined. You can add a new template by pressing the New... button.

In order to write the pattern of your method check how existing method patterns are described. For example your method might be described as :

```
public void stack1() {
    ${cursor}
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I don't want to make a new function template. I want to be able to access the functions of a structure (vector, stack, etc.) when the object is T and not something specific like int, float, string, etc.